# How to get position of ordered data in firebase?

Tags: performance, sorting, firebase

While Firebase does allow setting priority on data, I cant seem to find any way to get the position of my data in an ordered list.

For example, I have a leader board, where a user has a score (and thus the priority) of 400.

How do I find the position of this user in the leaderboard. For example, how do I know he is at position 5000 or 5, without iterating through the entire user list on every child add/remove/move event?

Comment: Are you having trouble with [getPriority()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/getpriority.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not an efficient way to do this in Firebase.

However, there are a few workarounds, and you can make this happen by doing one of the following:

1. Ensure that no two items ever have the same priority, or -
2. Load the entire list to look for the position of the target item on the client, or -
3. Run a server process, using the Firebase Node.js client, to monitor the list and update each item with the item's position in the list so that your clients don't have to.